# Why is the last line not executed by this code?

Tags: system, alarm

```
int main()
{
    alarm(2);
    printf("still going\n");
    while (1);
    printf("should this line be executed?\n");
}
```

I understand that alarm() will interrupt the execution, set the alarm to go off and hand it back. Why does the last line not get executed?

Comment: Because 1 never evaluate to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not printed because `while(1);` is an infinite loop. So, in the absence of the `alarm()` call, that would run forever.

However, the *signal* generated two seconds after you call `alarm()` will cause the program to terminate if you're not catching it.

What it *won't* do is cause just the loop to exit and the program to carry on. It will shut the program down, quick smart.

If you *do* catch the signal but your catching function just returns, it will end up back inside the infinite loop.

For more detail on those two cases, examine the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int fired = 0;
void handler (int sig) {
    fired = 1;
}

int main (void) {
    // signal (SIGALRM, handler);
    alarm  (2);
    printf ("Starting.\n");
    while (1) {
        if (fired) {
            fired = 0;
            printf ("Alarm fired.\n");
            alarm  (2);
        }
    }

    printf ("You will never see this.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you run that code, it will print out the `Starting` message, run for about two seconds, then exit without printing anything else. That's because you're not catching the signal so the default action is to just terminate the process.

If you uncomment the call to `signal()` (disregard for now that it's considered preferable to use `sigaction()` instead), you'll see the `Starting` message, followed by a `Alarm fired` message about every two seconds.

That's because you *are* catching the signal but, on exit, it returns to inside the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (1);
```

This is an infinite loop. Execution will never go beyond this.

Comment: but how will the program terminate if it never gets to the bottom of the block?

Comment: It will never terminate if you have a while(1) in it.

Comment: It won't, that's the problem. What's your intent in putting it there?

Comment: it is an example I am looking at

Comment: @TzvetlinVelev The code is then either being taken out of context, or is faulty.